# React app crashing when trying to import module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crash, mineflayer

Im trying to create a react that uses the 'mineflayer' module.
This is my code, the function is not being run, but just having the import crashes the app;

```
import mineflayer from 'mineflayer';

function createBot(account) {
    const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
        host: 'localhost',
        username: 'Bot',
        auth: 'microsoft'
    });
    account.setBot(bot);
}
```

I also tried some other different ways of importing it

```
import { mineflayer } from 'mineflayer';
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
```

with no luck.
This is my error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! slimegrabber@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the slimegrabber@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm new to both stack overflow and react, please be nice if this is a dumb question.

I tried different ways of importing it, and im expecting it to not crash.